# Прошивка Atmega32U4 скетчем arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, микроконтроллеры, avr, прошивка

Как прошить Atmega32U4 скетчем arduino с внутренним кварцем. В качестве программатора могу использовать arduino uno или USBASP. Знаю как прошить Atmega 8. Заранее спасибо

Comment: я тоже знаю как восьмую прошить скетчем. догадываюсь что эту аналогичным образом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нужно добавить описание микроконтроллера в файл boards.txt (директорий hardware/arduino/avr). Это нужно из-за нестандартной частоты тактирования - 8 МГц. Можно скопировать описание платы Leonardo, изменив частоту.
2. Скомпилировать загрузчик Caterina под частоту 8 МГц.
3. Подключить программатор к микроконтроллеру по ICSP.
4. Запрограммировать FUSE-биты (hfuse 0xD8, lfuse 0xF2, efuse 0xCB) с помощью программы avrdude.
5. Выбрать в IDE программатор и описанный микроконтроллер.
6. В IDE прошить загрузчик.

Далее:

- Либо загрузить скетч по USB.
- Либо скомпилировать скетч, найти его в директории /tmp (в Linux), и прошить hex-файл, используя программу avrdude.

Comment: Напишите готовое описание платы, пожалуйста.

Comment: И можно подробнее про загрузчик Caterina? Что с ним делать?

Comment: В Makefile изменить частоту на 8 МГц и скомпилировать Caterina-Leonardo.hex.